# How do I create an index in PostgreSQL on an expression that uses the date_trunc function?

Tags: postgresql

When I try to create an index in PostgreSQL on an expression over a table field of type `date`, using the `date_trunc` function, I get the following error.

```
functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
```

How do I work around this?

Judging by searches of StackOverflow and of Google, this seems to be a common question.  The trouble for me is that what seems to be the most common suggested solution doesn't work.  The most common suggested solution is to make the `date` field a `timestamp with timezone`.  Here's an example.

```
create table test (foo date);
create index on test (date_trunc('month', foo at time zone 'GMT'));
```

As far as I can tell, the form of that `create index...` statement is the commonly-suggested solution.  However, as I said it doesn't change the outcome for me.  I still get the error listed above.

This is PostgreSQL version 9.6.9, by the way.

Comment: I notice that what I claim to be the common solution (which is to add `at time zone...`) *does* work when the field in question is of type `timestamp`.  I cannot, however, get it to work when the field in question is of type `date`.

Comment: no, you must make it `timestamp without timezone`.

Comment: I think postgres prefers timestamptz over timestamp

Comment: what it actually is that `foo at time zone 'GMT'` first promotes foo to timestamp, and then applies `at time zone 'GMT'` which produces a `timestamptz`, but for this task you need `timestamp`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

only `date_trunc(text,interval)` and `date_trunc(text,timestamp)` are immutable

```
create index on test (date_trunc('month', foo::timestamp ));
```

the problem with  `foo at time zone 'GMT'` is that the expression `foo at time zone 'GMT'` is not itself immutable.  It's not immutable because it depends on the sessions  `time zone` setting.

confusingly `at time zone 'GMT'` is the inverse of `at time zone 'GMT'`  so if the column being indexed is of type `timestamptz` (*timestamp* *with* *timezone*) then that operation will fix the index expression.