# Create Postgresql index with date_trunc

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Relating to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333687/how-do-i-create-an-index-in-postgresql-on-an-expression-that-uses-the-date-trunc). I want to create an index that returns the same output as this query;

```sql
--takes 2005-10-12
select date_trunc('month',table_withdates.dateoftransfer::date)::Date
from table_withdates;
--returns 2005-10-01
```

The below will index but returns with timestamp added to date which is not what I want.

```sql
create index on table_withdates  (date_trunc('month', dateoftransfer::timestamp));
--returns 2005-10-01 00:00:00
```

Is it possible to create an index which returns the date in that format without a timestamp

Comment: thanks but when i run `select date_trunc('month',table_withdates.dateoftransfer::date)
from table_withdates;` it returns `2005-10-01 00:00:00+01` is that will the index will be?

Comment: dateoftransfer is type `date`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)

> The return value is of type timestamp or interval with all fields that are less significant than the selected one set to zero

So you need to cast the result of `date_trunc` to a date:

```
create index on table_withdates  (date_trunc('month', dateoftransfer)::date);
```

Note that in order to make the index usable for a query, you need to use the exact same expression, eg:

```
where date_trunc('month', dateoftransfer)::date  = ...
```